# $().html() will work only on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which has a div which says "Hide code"
I have also a p with stuff inside
That div is supposed to check if that p is visible.
If yes it will hide the p and change the content of the div to "Show code"
That works only on first time
I mean if the p is hidden it will be shown and forth back but the content of the div will only change to "Show code" and never back to "Hide code"
My code:

```
<div id="toggleCode">Hide code</div>
<p id="code">
    At first this is visible
</p>

#toggleCode{
    color:red;
    background:dodgerblue;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#codearea").css({"height":"15em","width":"15em","background":"gold","margin-top":"5em","border":"4px solid aqua"});

$(".ranges").change(function(){
    $tl=$("#tl").val()+"px "
    $tr=$("#tr").val()+"px "
    $bl=$("#bl").val()+"px "
    $br=$("#br").val()+"px "
    $code=$tl+$tr+$br+$bl;
    $("#codearea").css("border-radius",$code);
});
$("#toggleCode").click(
    function(){
        if ($("#code").is(":visible")){
            $("#toggleCode").html("Show code");
            $("#code").hide();
        }
        else{
            $("#toggle").html("Hide code");
            $("#code").show();
        }

    });
$("#resetCode").click(
    function () {
        $(".ranges").val(0);
        $("#codearea").css("border-radius",0);
    });

});
```

And a jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/9yrjuhv4/
Any ideas

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$("#toggleCode").html("Hide code")` instead of `$("#toggle").html("Hide code")`?

Comment: Try using adding/removing pre-defined classes instead of adding a list of custom properties. It's much neater, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$("#toggle").html("Hide code");
```

with

```
$("#toggleCode").html("Hide code");
```

---

Also, because of `$("#code").is(":visible")` you must wait until the animation finishes. I would recommend directly keeping the toggle state as a variable in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#toggleCode").click(
 function(){
        
  if ($("#code").is(":visible")){
   $(this).html("Show code");
  }
  else{
          $(this).html("HIDE code");
   $("#toggle").html("Hide code");
  }
  $("#code").toggle(789);
 });
```

```css
#toggleCode{
    color:red;
    background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggleCode">Hide code</div>
 <div id="code">
  At first this is visible
 </div>
```

try this : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvLkq2wu/1/)